# Difference between two rows in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a dataframe in Spark, by groupby column1 and date and calculated the amount.

```
val table = df1.groupBy($"column1",$"date").sum("amount")
```

```
Column1 |Date   |Amount
A   |1-jul  |1000
A   |1-june |2000
A   |1-May  |2000
A   |1-dec  |3000
A   |1-Nov  |2000
B   |1-jul  |100
B   |1-june |300    
B   |1-May  |400
B   |1-dec  |300
```

Now, I want to add new column, with difference between amount of any two dates from the table.

Answer (score 25):

You can use `Window` function if the calculation is fixed as *calculating difference between previous months*, or *calculating between previous two months* ... etc. For that you can use `lag` and `lead` function with `Window`.

But for that you need to change the date column as below so that it can be ordered.

```
+-------+------+--------------+------+
|Column1|Date  |Date_Converted|Amount|
+-------+------+--------------+------+
|A      |1-jul |2017-07-01    |1000  |
|A      |1-june|2017-06-01    |2000  |
|A      |1-May |2017-05-01    |2000  |
|A      |1-dec |2017-12-01    |3000  |
|A      |1-Nov |2017-11-01    |2000  |
|B      |1-jul |2017-07-01    |100   |
|B      |1-june|2017-06-01    |300   |
|B      |1-May |2017-05-01    |400   |
|B      |1-dec |2017-12-01    |300   |
+-------+------+--------------+------+
```

You can find the difference between previous month and current month by doing

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Column1").orderBy("Date_Converted")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("diff_Amt_With_Prev_Month", $"Amount" - when((lag("Amount", 1).over(windowSpec)).isNull, 0).otherwise(lag("Amount", 1).over(windowSpec)))
   .show(false)
```

You should have

```
+-------+------+--------------+------+------------------------+
|Column1|Date  |Date_Converted|Amount|diff_Amt_With_Prev_Month|
+-------+------+--------------+------+------------------------+
|B      |1-May |2017-05-01    |400   |400.0                   |
|B      |1-june|2017-06-01    |300   |-100.0                  |
|B      |1-jul |2017-07-01    |100   |-200.0                  |
|B      |1-dec |2017-12-01    |300   |200.0                   |
|A      |1-May |2017-05-01    |2000  |2000.0                  |
|A      |1-june|2017-06-01    |2000  |0.0                     |
|A      |1-jul |2017-07-01    |1000  |-1000.0                 |
|A      |1-Nov |2017-11-01    |2000  |1000.0                  |
|A      |1-dec |2017-12-01    |3000  |1000.0                  |
+-------+------+--------------+------+------------------------+
```

You can increase the lagging position for previous two months as

```
df.withColumn("diff_Amt_With_Prev_two_Month", $"Amount" - when((lag("Amount", 2).over(windowSpec)).isNull, 0).otherwise(lag("Amount", 2).over(windowSpec)))
  .show(false)
```

which will give you

```
+-------+------+--------------+------+----------------------------+
|Column1|Date  |Date_Converted|Amount|diff_Amt_With_Prev_two_Month|
+-------+------+--------------+------+----------------------------+
|B      |1-May |2017-05-01    |400   |400.0                       |
|B      |1-june|2017-06-01    |300   |300.0                       |
|B      |1-jul |2017-07-01    |100   |-300.0                      |
|B      |1-dec |2017-12-01    |300   |0.0                         |
|A      |1-May |2017-05-01    |2000  |2000.0                      |
|A      |1-june|2017-06-01    |2000  |2000.0                      |
|A      |1-jul |2017-07-01    |1000  |-1000.0                     |
|A      |1-Nov |2017-11-01    |2000  |0.0                         |
|A      |1-dec |2017-12-01    |3000  |2000.0                      |
+-------+------+--------------+------+----------------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 1):

**Assumming those two dates belong to each group of your table**

my imports :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{concat_ws,collect_list,lit}
```

Perpare the dataframe

```
scala> val seqRow = Seq(
 | ("A","1- jul",1000),
 | ("A","1-june",2000),
 | ("A","1-May",2000),
 | ("A","1-dec",3000),
 | ("B","1-jul",100),
 | ("B","1-june",300),
 | ("B","1-May",400),
 | ("B","1-dec",300))

seqRow: Seq[(String, String, Int)] = List((A,1- jul,1000), (A,1-june,2000), (A,1-May,2000), (A,1-dec,3000), (B,1-jul,100), (B,1-june,300), (B,1-May,400), (B,1-dec,300))

scala> val input_df = sc.parallelize(seqRow).toDF("column1","date","amount")
input_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column1: string, date: string ... 1 more field]
```

Now write a UDF for your case,

```
scala> def calc_diff = udf((list : Seq[String],startMonth : String,endMonth : String) => {
     |     //get the month and their values
     |     val monthMap = list.map{str =>
     |     val splitText = str.split("\\$")
     |     val month = splitText(0).split("-")(1).trim
     |
     |         (month.toLowerCase,splitText(1).toInt)
     |     }.toMap
     |
     |     val stMnth = monthMap(startMonth)
     |     val endMnth = monthMap(endMonth)
     |     endMnth - stMnth
     |
     | })
calc_diff: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
```

Now, Preparing the output

```
scala> val (month1 : String,month2 : String) = ("jul","dec")
month1: String = jul
month2: String = dec

scala> val req_df = group_df.withColumn("diff",calc_diff('collect_val,lit(month1.toLowerCase),lit(month2.toLowerCase)))
req_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column1: string, sum_amount: bigint ... 2 more fields]

scala> val req_df = group_df.withColumn("diff",calc_diff('collect_val,lit(month1.toLowerCase),lit(month2.toLowerCase))).drop('collect_val)
req_df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column1: string, sum_amount: bigint ... 1 more field]

scala> req_df.orderBy('column1).show
+-------+----------+----+
|column1|sum_amount|diff|
+-------+----------+----+
|      A|      8000|2000|
|      B|      1100| 200|
+-------+----------+----+
```

Hope, this is what you want.

Comment: @Anukush Singh Thanks for your response it was helpful, but for me subtraction not always for first row and last row, Can you help me how to calculate the middles rows also.

Comment: could you explain more when middle ones. Glad it was of some help

Comment: Sometimes I need to calculate the difference between amount of july month with feb month etc..., not always the first row and last row.The code you mentioned is for first row and last row for same "column_1"

Comment: Does that group has july as last month and feb as starting month but not in order then just use **orderBy** on column1,date and then run the logic

Comment: I want to calculate the amount difference for any two months from the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
(table.filter($"Date".isin("1-jul", "1-dec"))
      .groupBy("Column1")
      .pivot("Date")
      .agg(first($"Amount"))
      .withColumn("diff", $"1-dec" - $"1-jul")
).show
+-------+-----+-----+----+
|Column1|1-dec|1-jul|diff|
+-------+-----+-----+----+
|      B|  300|  100| 200|
|      A| 3000| 1000|2000|
+-------+-----+-----+----+
```