# Difference between two rows in Spark Java API

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark Dataset :

```
+----------+-----+----+
|      Date|Value|Name|
+----------+-----+----+
|2013-02-08|14.75| AAL|
|2013-02-11|14.46| AAL|
|2013-02-12|19.27| AAL|
|2013-02-11|13.66| FIN|
|2013-02-12|16.99| FIN|
+----------+-----+----+
```

I want to calculate the difference of subsequent days as follows:

```
+----------+-----+----+
|      Date| Diff|Name|
+----------+-----+----+
|2013-02-11| 0.29| AAL|
|2013-02-12| 4.81| AAL|
|2013-02-12| 3.33| FIN|
+----------+-----+----+
```

I see it is achievable in Scala as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527208/difference-between-two-rows-in-spark-dataframe/45528169#45528169) quite easily. Is there a way to do so in Java?

I was trying on similar lines but it doesn't really make sense to me:

```
WindowSpec windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Name").orderBy("Date");

modifiedDF = modifiedDF.withColumn("Diff", df.col("Value") - when((lag("Value", 1).over(windowSpec)).isNull(), 0).otherwise(lag("Value", 1).over(windowSpec)))
        .show(false);
```

Java complains that the subtraction operator cannot be applied on "`org.apache.spark.sql.Column`" types.

However, I do see a `.divide()` method implemented in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` and thus, the following works just fine:

```
modifiedDF = modifiedDF.withColumn("Diff", modifiedDF.col("Value").divide(when((lag("Value", 1).over(windowSpec)).isNull(), 0).otherwise(lag("Value", 1).over(windowSpec))));
```

I have two questions:

1) Is this the correct way of doing it?

2) If yes, why isn't there a .subtract implementation in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.subtract()` function I was looking for is named `.minus()`

```
modifiedDF = modifiedDF.withColumn("Diff",
                modifiedDF.col("Value")
                        .minus(when((lag("Value", 1).over(windowSpec)).isNull(), 0)
                                .otherwise(lag("Value", 1).over(windowSpec))));
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: There is also another way to defined lag: lag("Column", lagValue, defaultValue). In this case, you won't need the when() with otherwise().