# Find consecutive decline of total_sale on spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in table/Dataframe.

```
table/dataframe: temptable/temp_df 
StoreId,Total_Sales,Date
S1,10000,01-Jan-18
S1,20000,02-Jan-18
S1,25000,03-Jan-18
S1,30000,04-Jan-18
S1,29000,05-Jan-18--> total sales value is decline from previous value(04-jan-18)
S1,28500,06-Jan-18--> total sales value is decline from previous value(05-jan-18)
S1,25500,07-Jan-18--> total sales value is decline from previous value(06-jan-18)(output row)
S1,25500,08-Jan-18--> total sales value is constant from previous value(07-jan-18)
S1,30000,09-Jan-18
S1,29000,10-Jan-18-->same
S1,28000,11-Jan-18-->same
S1,25000,12-Jan-18-->same (output row)
S1,25000,13-Jan-18
S1,30000,14-Jan-18
S1,29000,15-Jan-18 
S1,28000,16-Jan-18
```

so I want those record from dataframe/table which are decline consecutive 3 times. if total value has a same total_sale then it will consider as neither decline nor increase.

The expected output is:

```
StoreId,Total_Sales,Date
S1,25500,07-Jan-18
S1,25000,12-Jan-18
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between two rows in Spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527208/difference-between-two-rows-in-spark-dataframe)

Comment: No it is not, I want to take the last row of consecutive declined 3rd row as expected output mentioned

Comment: why not S1 $28000  16-Jan-18 ?

Comment: @vikrantrana bcoz I want thrid row from value start decline.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

sc = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").\
config("spark.driver.memory","1g").\
config("spark.executor.cores",2).\
config("spark.max.cores",4).getOrCreate()



df = sc.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter",",").load("storesales.csv")

w = Window.partitionBy("StoreID").orderBy("Date")


df = df.withColumn("oneprev",f.lag("Total_Sales",1).over(w)).withColumn("twoprev",f.lag("Total_Sales",2).over(w))



df = df.withColumn("isdeclining",f.when((df["Total_Sales"].cast("double") < df["oneprev"].cast("double")) & (df["oneprev"].cast("double") < df["twoprev"].cast("double")) ,"declining").otherwise("notdeclining"))
df = df.withColumn("oneprev_isdeclining",f.lag("isdeclining",1).over(w)).withColumn("twoprev_isdeclining",f.lag("isdeclining",2).over(w))
```

df = df.filter((df["isdeclining"] == "declining") & (df["oneprev_isdeclining"] != "declining") & (df["twoprev_isdeclining"] != "declining")).select(["StoreID","Date","Total_Sales"])

```
df.show()
```

You can combine some of the lines into one line but ideally spark sql optimizer should take care of it

```
Sample input +-------+-----------+---------+
|StoreId|Total_Sales|     Date|
+-------+-----------+---------+
|     S1|      10000|01-Jan-18|
|     S1|      20000|02-Jan-18|
|     S1|      25000|03-Jan-18|
|     S1|      30000|04-Jan-18|
|     S1|      29000|05-Jan-18|
|     S1|      28500|06-Jan-18|
|     S1|      25500|07-Jan-18|
|     S1|      25500|08-Jan-18|
|     S1|      30000|09-Jan-18|
|     S1|      29000|10-Jan-18|
|     S1|      28000|11-Jan-18|
|     S1|      25000|12-Jan-18|
|     S1|      25000|13-Jan-18|
|     S1|      30000|14-Jan-18|
|     S1|      29000|15-Jan-18|
+-------+-----------+---------+    

Desired Output :

+-------+---------+-----------+
|StoreID|     Date|Total_Sales|
+-------+---------+-----------+
|     S1|06-Jan-18|      28500|
|     S1|11-Jan-18|      28000|
+-------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: your solution is working for the only two-digit match but what if data is in 25500 it will fail. thanks for your effort.

Comment: It would work for all digits i am assuming you are commenting based on substring(Total_Sales, 2). That is done to remove $ and  its the start index not end index. You can try it yourself .

Comment: try this input you will get know what am i saying:StoreId,Total_Sales,Date
S1,10000,01-Jan-18
S1,20000,02-Jan-18
S1,25000,03-Jan-18
S1,30000,04-Jan-18
S1,29000,05-Jan-18
S1,28500,06-Jan-18
S1,25500,07-Jan-18
S1,25500,08-Jan-18
S1,30000,09-Jan-18
S1,29000,10-Jan-18
S1,28000,11-Jan-18
S1,25000,12-Jan-18
S1,25000,13-Jan-18
S1,30000,14-Jan-18
S1,29000,15-Jan-18
S1,28000,16-Jan-18

Comment: This input will not work as the code would expect $ based on your details in the question . For this input you will have to remove the substring operation .

Comment: it obviously depends on the input format . If your input can contain $ or without $ then will have to add the logic to first check for the $ but the approach to find declining or not will work. If you change the line df = df.withColumn("isdeclining",f.when((f.expr("substring(Total_Sales, 1)").cast("double") < f.expr("substring(oneprev, 1)").cast("double")) & (f.expr("substring(oneprev, 1)").cast("double") < f.expr("substring(twoprev, 1)").cast("double")) ,"declining").otherwise("notdeclining")) . To use 1 instead of 2 which is nothing but not having substring will work for your input

Comment: $ is basically indicating the type of sale

Comment: Probably i am not getting your question . From my understand you mainly wanted to know on how you can check if value had declined 3 consecutive times and you want to filter the line where the prev value is larger than current one and the prev to prev is larger than prev . That will work with the logic in the code which is basically using windowing on the input format if $ is type or currency if that will not be part of  the input then if we just remove the logic  of substring the code will work .

Comment: df = df.withColumn("isdeclining",f.when((df["Total_Sales"].cast("double") < df["oneprev"].cast("double")) & (df["oneprev"].cast("double") < df["twoprev"].cast("double")) ,"declining").otherwise("notdeclining"))

Comment: giving the wrong result output must be  07,12,16 date

Comment: Even for 6th and 11th condition  of last 3 decline holds good. and i don't have 16 in my input. Are you looking for a output where if the output has 6th and 7th then only  7th has to be displayed ?

Comment: the output must be 3 row from it parents their value declined you can check-in input data sample

Comment: it's partially correct. I want 3rd row from  its parent decline.

Comment: I hope the latest code satisfies that condition as well

Comment: Nope it is not giving expected output

Comment: probably if you provide full input and output someone can help which can be just copy pasted

Comment: I had already added sample output and expected output. you solution is not giving me as the desired output. you can check by yourself.

Comment: The  input doesn't  have certain values mentioned example 16th jan and it had dollar .. anyway you will know better so it's up to you thanks and sorry I couldn't provide the exact copy paste answer